# WPF using Frame to show a WebSite - flash problem

Tags: wpf

I have a small problem. I use a Frame to show a website, unfortunateli some of my websites use flash, and seems to want to install a flash plugin - my frame doesnt seem to accept this behavior so it fails giving me a http 500 internal server error. Any one having any experiences in how to show the web site or install the flash plugin (its already installed in my regular IE - i can browse the site without problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems flash wasn't the problem, it was installed and seems to be used.

Answer (score 0):

For people searching and found this, had a similar problem, this was the solution: [WPF Application hosting a HTML page, the flash is disabled, how to enable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927548/wpf-application-hosting-a-html-page-the-flash-is-disabled-how-to-enable/2928912#2928912)