# WPF Application hosting a HTML page, the flash is disabled, how to enable?

Tags: wpf, browser, frame

I have made a small application where the user can browse to a web page, im using a "Frame" for the purpose and passes a URL to it, it then renders the destination page as HTMl. The page im trying to show shows some flash animation and my "Frame" browser cant show it, i suspect that the browser plugin is disabled, but how to enable, when the hosted "Frame" browser has no toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The problem wasnt enabling/disabling, but the fact that i set my WPF application to compile to "Any CPU" and im on a 64 bits computer. Flash does not run in 64 bits, so i changed my compile platform to x86 - and voila, it works.